# How to establish VPN from Azure to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, azure-networking

I am trying to establish a VPN between AZURE and AWS. I have the vnet gateway public address to the AWS support team and I received the below config text file.

```
Outside IP Addresses:
 - Customer Gateway                 : xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx <=== I see my Public IP here 
 - Virtual Private Gateway          : xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx <=== Public IP from AWS VPC

Inside IP Addresses
 - Customer Gateway                 :     169.254.xx.xx/xx
 - Virtual Private Gateway             : 169.254.xx.xx/xx
```

Now on my Azure when I create the local gateway I input the Customer Gateway address in the IP address field and the IP address of the "Virtual Private Gateway" in the "Address space" field.

I am seeing the message that this CIDR block is invalid.

I am stuck at this point and looking for some responses and suggestions, please.

I followed these links:

[Step By Step Connect your AWS and Azure environments with a VPN](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ITOps-Talk-Blog/Step-By-Step-Connect-your-AWS-and-Azure-environments-with-a-VPN/ba-p/339211)

[How to connect between azure and aws with managed services](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-connect-between-azure-and-aws-with-managed-services-4b03ec334e8a)

Comment: What is the Address Space for your AWS VPC?  You need to specify a subnet that is in that Address Space.  Since you are not showing us those two values, it's hard to say what the issue is.

Comment: The actual address space on the AWS side from our network diagram is 192.168.x.x range, but I'm not sure about the actual CIDR block. At the same time per AWS documentation says the provided range is correct: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/s2svpn/VPNTunnels.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Ken W MSFT
Our AWS counterpart provided the proper VPC IP ranges on their side and it fixed my issue.